# Sending AJAX call to the same php file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following functions. One is supposed to receive an id, which is then supposed to be transmitted via AJAX, by way of a POST request.

Yet, while I know the "initiateSubCategories" function is working, for whatever reason the ajax function refuses to work. It's supposed to send the data to the very same file it's called in, and I have a feeling that this may be the issue.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here? I've tried validating my JavaScript via [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/), but all that has given me is some nitty gritty complaints about my code format (which is not the issue here, but will be after I've fixed this).

Here's my code:

```
function sendAjaxDataViaPost(pathToFile, ajaxData) {  
    $.post(pathToFile, function(ajaxData) {
        alert("Data loaded: " + ajaxData);
        $('#pageOne').append('<pre>' + ajaxData '</pre>');
    });
}

function initiateSubCategories(parent) {
    //$("#pageOne").append("<pre>" + parent + "</pre>");
    sendAjaxDataViaPost('form.php', parent);
    <?php
        $categories = $this->formData->getCategories($_POST['value']);
    ?>
    printSubCategories(<?=$categories;?>);
}
```

So, what is it that I'm doing wrong? I've tried this in both Firefox and Chrome, and neither have been able to produce anything.

**Update**

I changed the function to use the following format:

```
$.post(pathToFile, { id: ajaxData }, function(ajaxData) {
    alert("Data loaded: " + ajaxData);
    $('#pageOne').append('<pre>' + ajaxData '</pre>');
});
```

yet, when I try to land a `$_POST['id']`, it tells me that it's not referenced.

???

**Update 2**

I just found in FireBug's console that my "initiateSubCategories" function is undefined. What I'd like to know is how this is possible...

I'll post my entire code - a second pair of eyes may really help on this one.

```
<?php 

$target = JPATH_BASE.DS."index.php?action=com_adsmanager&task=save&Itemid=".$this->itemId;
$saveTarget = JPATH_BASE.DS."index.php?action=com_adsmanager&task=Itemid=".$this->itemId;

function populateCategories($parent, FormData $formData) {
    $categories = $formData->getCategories($parent);
    foreach($categories as $section => $row){
        ?>
           <option value=<?=$row['id'];
        ?>>
        <?php 
            echo $row['name']; 
        ?>
            </option>
        <?php       
    }
}

?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function sendAjaxDataViaPost(pathToFile, ajaxData) {  
        $.post(pathToFile, {'id' : ajaxData}, function(ajaxData) {
            alert("Data loaded: " + ajaxData);
            $('#pageOne').append('<pre>' + ajaxData '</pre>');
        });
    }

    function initiateSubCategories(parent) {
        sendAjaxDataViaPost('form.php', parent);
        $("#pageOne").apppend('<pre>' + <?=$_POST;?> + '</pre>'));
    }

    function printSubCategories(categories) {
        for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
            var opt = document.createElement("option");
            opt.text = categories['name'];
            opt.value = categories['id'];

            $("#subcategories").append(opt);
        }    
    } 

</script>

<div id="pageOne">
    <form action=<?=$saveTarget;?> method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <select name="category" id="categories" class="ads_categories" onclick="initiateSubCategories(this.value);">
            <option value="0">--Please choose a category--</option>
            <?php populateCategories(0, $this->formData); ?>
        </select> 
        <select name="category" id="subcategories" class="ads_subcategories">
            <option value="0">--Please choose a subcategory--</option>
        </select> 
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Your post function is not well formatted according JQuery's specs, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: it's not empty; I tested it earlier, and the value was outputted to my screen.

Comment: @zequinha-bsb How exactly would that help my function though? I'll try it real quick, but it would be good to know why that's useful. Thanks for the suggestions, everyone.

Comment: Still not working, unfortunately, though I appreciate the suggestion. Is there anything else? I'd like to at least see it pop up with an alert telling me that it's successful. Edit: I don't even get an alert, which is the problem.

Comment: Ok, will do. I found another problem though. My console is telling me that "initiateSubCategories" is not defined. How could this be? It's defined perfectly. I'll be sure to post the source for my entire code and then I'll get back to you on what happens when I try it with your suggestions. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your post call to

```
$.post(pathToFile, { 'id': ajaxData }, function(ajaxData) {
    alert("Data loaded: " + ajaxData);
    $('#pageOne').append('<pre>' + ajaxData '</pre>');
});
```

I am assuming that you are sending some value through ajaxData before you call

```
function sendAjaxDataViaPost(pathToFile, ajaxData) {
```

Comment: Tried, still not working :(. I think it's the "undefined" functions I keep receiving. I've tried everything. Is it possible to put jQuery in an external js file?

Comment: I don't know php but isn't this wrong: function populateCategories($parent, FormData $formData) { ... what is FormData doing alone there?

Comment: Is populateCategories a PHP or javascript function?

Comment: populateCategories is a php function.